# T4MVCVB doesn't work on clean install?

Tags: vb.net, t4mvc

I just installed T4MVCVB and it won't compile:

```
Error   1   Compiling transformation: Invalid token 'this' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    c:\...\T4MVCVB.tt   1   1
Error   2   Compiling transformation: Method must have a return type    c:\...\T4MVCVB.tt   1   6
Error   3   Compiling transformation: Type expected c:\...\T4MVCVB.tt   1   12
```

Note that the line number is 1 for each of these errors, so there's no way at all to see what line it doesn't like.

How can I figure out what the problem is so I can generate typed helpers for VB?

**Edit**: After some cleanup, now I get the following compiler error, and the line number of the problem:

```
Error   112 Running transformation: System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))
at EnvDTE80.CodeFunction2.get_Attributes()
at  {long call stack}
```

The line it doesn't like is:

```
// Ignore methods that are marked as not being actions
if (GetAttribute(method.Attributes, "System.Web.Mvc.NonActionAttribute") != null)
    continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version made for VB. Here is the [T4MVCVB Nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/T4MVCVB/)

If it's still breaking before generating the .vb files, I would uncomment these two lines near the top of T4MVCVB.tt and see if you can find the problem location.

```
//System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
//System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Comment: It's breaking before, because of compiler errors in the tt file.  I don't have those lines though, so I must have a different version of the file.  After fiddling around, I now get different errors, which I've updated in my original question.

Comment: It sounds like you are using an older version then. Try installing the  [Nuget Package T4MVCVB](http://www.nuget.org/packages/T4MVCVB/) and see if it works.

Comment: That fixed it.  I was using the files directly, because I didn't see the NuGet package for the VB version, and I guess the package does important things.  Could you post this comment as the answer so I can accept it.  Your original answer is less directly relevant, I think.